# How to deallocate a compiled pattern in PCRE?

Tags: c, pcre

I working on a system, which need to compile and match a lot of regexes. But these regexes are usually not reused *so I want to deallocate them, when I don't need them anymore*.

After scanning through [PCRE API spec](http://mushclient.com/pcre/) I didn't found a function that can be used to this.

There must be a way to do this somehow. I cannot imagine a popular regex library without this functionality.

So is there a way to get rid of unused regex patterns?

Comment: http://www.pcre.org/ and http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is up to the caller to free the memory (via `pcre_free`) when it is no longer required.

Source: [API docs](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)

Comment: pfff, I embarrassingly overlooked this. Thx.